# Integrate struts2 spring hibernate with ehcache

Tags: spring, hibernate, struts2, ehcache

I am new one to Hibernate. I need step by step procedure for how integrate a Struts2, Spring3.0 and Hibernate with Ehcache.

Answer (score 0):

Integration spring - struts2 : 
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/web-integration.html#struts

Integration of ehcache is described here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html

If you have precise questions, maybe I can provide more specific answers.

Comment: i already integrate struts2,spring,hibernate(manual config without annotation). now i need integrate ehcache to that integrated file.

Answer (score 0):

Ehcache works with hibernate(ORM) .
**[Steps by Steps Tutorial](http://ehcache.org/documentation/integrations/hibernate).**

Comment: Well you can integrate Ehcache with Spring certainly (to cache, invalidate, cache entries when calling into beans)